# Restart shiny-server on centos

Tags: r, centos, shiny, shiny-server

I have shiny-server installed and I am using it to host my shiny apps installed on a centos server. I'm pretty sure its installed correctly because it was working as expected until the server crashed, since the server recently crashed I need to restart shiny-server.

I  tried both:

```
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```

and

```
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server.service
```

but I get the error message:

*Failed to issue method call: Unit shiny-server.service failed to load: No such file or directory.*

However I can see the file shiny-server.service in the folder I am running the command from. Does anyone know why this is or what I should do to fix it?

If it helps the shiny-server.service file is located in the directory /opt/shiny-server/config/systemd/shiny-server.service

Comment: Try `sudo restart shiny-server`

Comment: @Gopala if I do that I get this error sudo: restart: command not found

Comment: Try `stop` and then `start`. Does that work? Not sure. Things work for me without that `systemctl` on linux.

Comment: @Gopala Thanks for your suggestions! however stop does not work either. I get the same command not found message

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the service has not been registered.

Try;

`chkconfig --list shiny-server` it should return something like;

`shiny-server   0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off`

If nothing comes back then you need to `chkconfig --add shiny-server` then re run the above commands to verify its registered, then you should be able to access it via the service manager.

- I'm presuming the service is called `shiny-server` but if not replace it with the correct name.

[This](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/#tab-ee5aa2d16677cd919d1) link may also provide some additional info.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but it took me a long time to figure out and I can probably save someone some time. 
Shiny had installed in `/opt`directory and the shiny-server.service is located at: `opt/shiny-server/config/systemd/shiny-server.service`

What I did was copy it to systemd: `cp /opt/shiny-server/config/systemd/shiny-server.service /etc/systemd/system/`

The I just started it the normal way: `sudo systemctl start shiny-server,service`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being that I needed to create a link between the shiny-server.service file that was in my shiny-server/config folder and the /systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants folder.

Updating that link allowed me to use systemctl to restart the shiny server correctly.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer...I am facing the same issue and I am new to both CentOS and Shiny-Server

Comment: @Apricot I created a symbolic link by using the command :  ln -s shiny-server.service /systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants         this command create a link between the .service file and the directory where centos seems to be looking for it. Does that help?

Comment: many thanks for the reply...i used the command...but got a message file already exists...guess the trouble is somewhere else....have created a new question in SO...thank you again.